# How to close tag in comments with php

Tags: php

In my application people are posting comments, and some times the user doesn't close the tags so it destroys all my layout.

I allow user to post html comment.

For example they post this way :

```
<center><b>Hello
```

So what I want is to close the tags on it and make it this way:

```
<center><b>Hello</b></center>
```

I searched on Google but din't find a good solution so I am here.

I tried this method but it does not work.

```
$yourText = $row['content'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("$yourText");
$yourText = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to close all the opened HTML tags in your content :

```
function closeHtmlTags($html) {

    preg_match_all('#<(?!meta|img|br|hr|input\b)\b([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result);
    $openedtags = $result[1];
    preg_match_all('#</([a-z]+)>#iU', $html, $result);
    $closedtags = $result[1];
    $len_opened = count($openedtags);

    if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened) {
        return $html;
    }
    $openedtags = array_reverse($openedtags);

    for ($i=0; $i < $len_opened; $i++) {
        if (!in_array($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)) {
            $html .= '</'.$openedtags[$i].'>';
        } else {
            unset($closedtags[array_search($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)]);
        }
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Just call :

```
$content = closeHtmlTags($content);
```

This will return the content will all HTML tags close.

Also you can use the PHP extension `php_tidy`

```
$tidy = new Tidy();
$content = $tidy->repairString($str, array(
    'output-xml' => true,
    'input-xml' => true
));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I will try this way seems safe :) @Sabari

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [HTML Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<html>a html document</html>
<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();

// Specify configuration
$config = array(
           'indent'         => true,
           'output-xhtml'   => true,
           'wrap'           => 200);

// Tidy
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

// Output
echo $tidy;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't allow users to post HTML! They can modify your site, add Javascript, do anything they want.

Make sure to remove HTML formatting with [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the number of open tags, then search for the number of closing tags and making sure that number matches - if it doesn't don't submit and let the user know.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and dyrtiest way would be this:

```
$yourText = $row['content'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("$yourText");
$otherText = $doc->saveHTML();

if(!empty($otherText)){
    //the usertext was good html
}else{
    $yourText = strip_tags($yourText);
}
```

but you might end up with some serious XXS injections!!!

Comment: @deerox but remember the XXS injection. you really should consider using tidy or something to restrict the user from using some tags like script or something like that what really could do some (reputational) damage